# How can i improve performances when using django queryset?

Tags: sql, django, orm

I'm trying to make a news feed. Each time the page is called, server must send multiple items. One item contain a post, number of likes, number of comments, number of comment children, comments data, comment children data etc.

My problem is, each time my page is called, it takes more than 5 secondes to be loaded. I've already implemented a caching system. But it's still slow.

```
       posts = Posts.objects.filter(page="feed").order_by('-likes')[:'10'].cache()
    posts = PostsSerializer(post,many=True)

    hasPosted = Posts.objects.filter(page="feed",author="me").cache()
    hasPosted = PostsSerializer(hasPosted,many=True)


    for post in post.data:

        commentsNum = Comments.objects.filter(parent=posts["id"]).cache(ops=['count'])
        post["comments"] = len(commentsNum)
        comments = Comments.objects.filter(parent=posts["id"]).order_by('-likes')[:'10'].cache()
        liked = Likes.objects.filter(post_id=posts["id"],author="me").cache()

        comments = CommentsSerializer(comments,many=True)
        commentsObj[posts["id"]] = {}
        for comment in comments.data:

            children = CommentChildren.objects.filter(parent=comment["id"]).order_by('date')[:'10'].cache()
            numChildren = CommentChildren.objects.filter(parent=comment["id"]).cache(ops=['count'])
            posts["comments"] = posts["comments"] + len(numChildren)
            children = CommentChildrenSerializer(children,many=True)
            liked = Likes.objects.filter(post_id=comment["id"],author="me").cache()



            for child in children.data:

                if child["parent"] == comment["id"]:
                    liked = Liked.objects.filter(post_id=child["id"],author="me").cache()
```

I'm trying to find a simple method to fetch all these data quicker and without unnecessary database hit. I need to reduce the loading time from 5 secs to less than 1 if possible.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have a look at `select_related` and `prefetch_related`

Comment: You have a triple nested loop. No wonder it's slow. look into what @The_Cthulhu_Kid has said. Then let's look at your indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the number of children as a integer on the comment field that gets updated every time a comment is added or removed. That way, you won't have to query for that value. You can do this using signals.
2. Add an **ArrayField**(if you're using postgres) or something similar on your **Profile** model that stores all the primary keys of **Liked** posts. Instead of querying the Likes model, you would be able to do this:

   profile = Profile.objects.get(name='me')

   liked = True if comment_pk in profile.liked_posts else False
3. Use **select_related** to CommentChildren instead of making an extra query for it.

Implementing these 3 items will get rid of all the db queries being executed in the **"comment in comments.data"** forloop which is probably taking up the majority of the processing time.

If you're interested, check out [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) which enables you to see what queries are being executed on every page.